# wxwidget assert failure failed in mswgetstyle()

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I coded an application using `WxWidgets`. When I run it. I have this error message :

assert failure failed in `mswgetstyle(): unkonwn border style`.

[image]

When i chose to cancel the application work fine. What does this mean.

Comment: Build the debug version of your program, run it inder the debugger and trace back to where in YOUR code the problem occurs.  Often this will make it obvious what the problem is.  Otherwise, post the code that calls the routine that asserts.

Comment: I can't use the debug mode because i have some problem with configuration under codeblocks. And did researche for the MSWGetStyle() in my code and i did not find it.

Comment: OK, you should first sort out your problem with debug.  This is much more serious and needs to be fixed before you can continue.  Please post a question regarding the debug problem, and add a link here so I can maybe help.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you used an invalid style somewhere in your code, it's impossible to say anything more without seeing your code.

I agree with ravenspoint comment however: your first problem is to make debugging work. You're making your life much more difficult completely unnecessarily if you can't use it.